# UIPangesture blocks my custom control's touch move events

Tags: ios, iphone, custom-controls, uigesturerecognizer

I have a container view controller with pan gesture to use swipe left and right .
while swipe right, i am bringing another view from right side.

But, in the home screen I have a custom dial control. the dial control will rotate to select an option.

Now, the problem is : if i am not using the pan gesture to identify the left and right swipe of the screen - my custom dial control works well, i can able to rotate it by finger.

if i am using pan gesture to identify the swipe on my screen - It blocks the custom control's rotation.

can any one help me out on this?

thanks,
bala.

Answer (score 0):

The pan gesture captures the touches it recognizes as a pan gesture. That includes up/down panning as well. Assuming your dial uses up/down panning gestures, you have two options: a) use UISwipeGestureRecognizers with the appropriate allowed directions set, or b) implement a UIPanGestureRecognizer subclass that fails when swiping up/down.